# Swift Array in CoreData

Tags: arrays, core-data, swift3

I want to store an array with 28 entries to my coreData. Is there any way to do this?
I tried it with this code but it looks like that this code is only rewriting the value.

```
let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PillTook",
                                             in:managedContext)

    let value = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                insertInto: managedContext)

    for var index in 0...27 {

        value.setValue(false, forKey: "took")

        do {
            try managedContext.save()

            pillTook.append(value)

        } catch let error as NSError  {
            print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your code creates only one `NSManagedObject`, and updates the value of its `took` attribute in the for loop.  Move the `let value = ...` line into the for loop to create a new `NSManagedObject` for each iteration.  I would also recommend saving the context only once after the for loop, instead of saving at each iteration:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PillTook", in:managedContext)

for var index in 0...27 {

    let value = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: managedContext)
    value.setValue(false, forKey: "took")
    pillTook.append(value)
}
do {
    try managedContext.save()
} catch let error as NSError  {
    print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
}
```